# waitForNavigation causes timeout if page isn't reloading

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm running:

```
    await page.waitForNavigation()
```

But if the page isn't reloading, I the timeout:

```
    TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
```

I can't be certain that hte page is going to reload, so I need to wrap the the await page.waitForNavigation in something that will only run should the page reload. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript error handling basics may be the way :

```
Try{  
  await page.waitForNavigation()  
}  
catch(error){  
  //"do something if you got an error in the Try"  
}
```

doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch
or : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understand correctly , but if you're not sure when navigation is going to happen , try

```
await page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 0})
```

it'll wait without timeout

Comment: The problem is the page may not be navigation at all, and this is why I see the timeout error. So what I need to do is check if the page is reloading and then if it is, set the waitForNavigation.

Comment: @ditto well if the navigation happens you cant say wait for it , it already has happen  .... what happens if there is no navigation  ? it shows a new element or something ? why and when it navigates ? i need to explain a little more about how page works